# Run google apps script when a form loads

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload file to my google drive. I have searched and found the relevant code for uploading file. I have tested it and it is working.

I want to attach the same code in my google forms. But the code runs when I am editing the form instead of when form is being viewed. Is it possible to run the google app script function when form is viewed? If yes, how?

Comment: Hope this is helpful: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers

Comment: @KRR This seems to be for editing or form submit. I want a trigger when a google form loads. I want this because I want custom functionality not present. Please share if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts can only be used to create a form or to process responses after the live form has been submitted. It can not interact with a live form.